# Meteor - Return Collection Object from Method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to return a collection object from a Meteor method based on a set session.

Here's the method call:

```
Template.batches.search = function () {
    if (typeof Session.get('search-parameters') != 'undefined') {

        var searchParameters = Session.get('search-parameters');

        return Meteor.call('search', searchParameters, function(error , result){
            if (error) {
                console.log(error.reason);
            } else{
                return result;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the method being calledL

```
Meteor.methods({
    search: function (session) {
        return Batches.find({event: { $regex: session}});
    }
});
```

I've read that a method cannot return a collection object and to use fetch() instead.  This returns an array, however, I'm unable to iterate over the array like a colleciton object to return the results.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Template helpers need to be synchronous. There are a few ways to solve this, but here's an example:

```
Template.batches.created = function() {
  // this will be cleaned up for you when the template is destroyed
  this.autorun(function() {
    var search = Session.get('search-parameters');
    Meteor.subscribe('batchesForSearch', search);
  });
};

Template.batches.helpers({
  search: function() {
    var search = Session.get('search-parameters');
    return Batches.find({event: {$regex: search}});
  }
});
```

In the `batches` template, create an autorun which subscribes to `batchesForSearch` whenever the session changes. Once the documents arrive on the client, they will be made available to your template via the `search` helper.

The `batchesForSearch` publish function could look something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('batchesForSearch', function(search) {
  check(search, String);

  if (_.isEmpty(search)) {
    // make sure we do not publish the entire collection if search is empty 
    return this.ready();
  } else {
    return Batches.find({event: {$regex: search}});
  }
});
```

Note that we are careful to avoid publishing the entire collection in case the search is empty.